# Failed to push some refs to gerrit as getting as error running hooks

Tags: git, push, hook

I am trying to push git data to gerrit using the command "git push origin --all" but it throws an error as below:

```
remote: error: internal error while processing changes
```

To ssh://url_path:8282/SI_VF.git
! [remote rejected]   git-svn -> git-svn (Error running hook /opt/gerrit/hooks/ref-update)
! [remote rejected]   master -> master (internal error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@url-path:8282/SI_VF.git'

Not able to figure out what to do to fix this error.

Comment: The hook `/opt/gerrit/hooks/ref-update` exits with a non-zero status but it does not echo why. So you can ask your gerrit administrator for help.

Comment: What to ask?, could you elaborate.

Comment: There should be someone who is in charge of the gerrit system.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay, putting light on it. I was trying to do this by changing in config file but after in touch with admin they disabled the hooks for this project.It works.